# Menu with permissions in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I am creating a modular menu in Django that has the following structure;

```
class Pagina(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

class Voce(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    Pagine = models.ManyToManyField(Pagina)
    Permesso = models.ForeignKey(Permesso, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

class Menu(models.Model):
    Voci = models.ManyToManyField(Voce)
```

I need to check if the user has the required permission to see the submenu(permission that is in a group).

The menu is rendered the following way;

```
{% for voce in menu.Voci.all %}
                        <li class="m-menu__item  m-menu__item--submenu m-menu__item--rel {% ifequal parent voce.nome %}m-menu__item--active{% endifequal %}" m-menu-submenu-toggle="click" aria-haspopup="true">
                            <a href="javascript:;" class="m-menu__link m-menu__toggle">
                                <span class="m-menu__item-here"></span><span class="m-menu__link-text">{{voce}}</span><i class="m-menu__hor-arrow la la-angle-down"></i><i class="m-menu__ver-arrow la la-angle-right"></i>
                            </a>
                            <div class="m-menu__submenu m-menu__submenu--classic m-menu__submenu--left"><span class="m-menu__arrow m-menu__arrow--adjust"></span>
                                <ul class="m-menu__subnav">
                                    {% for pagina in voce.Pagine.all %}
                                    <li class="m-menu__item {% ifequal request.path pagina.url %}m-menu__item--active{% endifequal %}" aria-haspopup="true">
                                        <a href="{{pagina.url}}" class="m-menu__link ">
                                          <i class="m-menu__link-bullet m-menu__link-bullet--line"><span></span></i>
                                          <span class="m-menu__link-title"><span class="m-menu__link-wrap"><span class="m-menu__link-text">{{pagina.nome}}</span></span></span>
                                       </a>
                                    </li>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        {% endfor %}
```

The check would need to happen just after the first for loop starts in order to determine whether or not to display that particular submenu.

The "gruppo" object of the user is a foreignkey relation to a personalized Group object, which has a ManyToMany relation with different permissions, each having a name. I need to check if a user has the same permission as the "Voce" model currently being looped through.

Thank you for your time,

Matteo

Comment: This looks like writing *business logic* in templates. Usually that is not a good idea, this should be handled in the view.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see how I could handle this login in a view; the menu object is passed through a context processor. Do you have an idea how I could do that?